# Find lengths of inscribed right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Suppose I have a right triangle $\triangle BCD$, inscribed in a circle $Q$ with radius $s$, where $BD$ is the diameter of the circle. Solve for the lengths of the sides of $\triangle BCD$ in terms of $s$?

Can I answer the problem using only the information given?

**Try:** We know that $BD$ is $2s$ so:
$$4s^2=BC^2+CD^2$$

Suppose $\angle DQC$ is $\theta$, I know that $\angle DBC=\frac\theta2$, $\angle\hat {QDC}=\angle\hat {QCD}=\frac{180-\theta}2, \ \angle BQC=180-\theta$ and $\angle QBC=\angle QCB = \frac\theta2$. I'm using the following equations, but I seem to be going around circles:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\theta}{CD}&=\frac{\cos\frac\theta2}{s}\\
BC^2&=2s^2-2s^2\cos\theta\\
\frac{\sin\frac\theta2}{s}&=\frac{\sin\theta}{BC}
\end{align}$$

Comment: If $BD$ is the diameter of a circle $\Gamma$ and $C\in\Gamma\setminus\{B,D\}$, then $\widehat{BCD}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ independently from the choice of $C$. $BD=2s$ and the lenghts of $BC,CD$ can be any positive numbers such that $BC^2+CD^2=4s^2=BD^2$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. The problem really is not solvable unless there are other qualifications